# Problems installing rEFInd through windows after Ubuntu install

Tags: command-line, windows-7, error-handling, refind

I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows and I can't figure out how to boot into Ubuntu. So now I'm trying to install rEFInd. Fallowing the instructions [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#windows) I ran into a problem running the `xcopy /E refind S:\EFI\refind\` command. I get this error, "Invalid drive specification 0 File(s) copied"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the ESP wasn't mounted at `S:`. Did you get any errors with the `mountvol` command earlier in the procedure? If so, you should correct those errors.

As an alternative, consider downloading the USB flash drive or CD-R version of rEFInd and booting with it. If you can get into Ubuntu in that way, you can install the Debian package or PPA, which should set things up automatically.

Comment: I had no errors with the `mountvol` step. I tried putting rEFInd on a cd and I managed to get into Ubuntu and I installed rEFInd there. Thanks for the help.